# Mixing battery sizes

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

Apologies if this is the wrong Stack. I suspect this is a bit of a lowest-common-denominator question. I've got a cheap little Christmas tree covered in blue festive lights that takes 3 size-C batteries. I only had 2 size-C batteries.

Knowing literally *nothing* of electronics (asides "don't stick a fork into a power socket, it'll probably hurt"), I decided to ram an AA in the third slot. I observed two outcomes:

- The tree lit up
- I didn't die (probably)

[image: Mixed batteries]

So, is it ok to mix batteries like this? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The small cell will run out of juice before the others do.  The two good cells will continue to force current through the dead cell, which will attempt to charge it backward.  The cell will be ruined (not a big deal) and it is very likely to leak (possibly a big deal).

Until that time, the battery will function.  Also, after the small cell dies, you now have two half-used C-cells to manage.

Comment: Also note that each piece is called a "cell", and cells are combined to make a "battery".

Comment: Fair enough. So long as it's not going to damage the tree or anything, think I'm just going to keep it in there until I buy another C-cell. Not too fussed about wasting the C-cells, think I've had them about 4 years and this is the first time I've needed them.

Comment: The other option is to use 3 AA cells.

Comment: Nice to know about the cell/battery thing too. Always interesting to find things on Stacks well outside my profession that clear up old misconceptions (or are just plain ol' interesting) :)

Comment: @RJR Neat, just tried that and it worked. I'd assumed bigger battery = more power; therefore smaller batteries = not enough power. Really don't know anything about this kinda thing. Time to retreat back to my world of databases. Cheers guys~

Comment: Sometimes the circuit needs the power and the little AA's won't cut it.  But often the bigger cells are used just to make it last longer.